# chrome extension not running search into divs jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On chrome extension after doing an ajax call it should search inside paragraphs on divs with id #lead and #detail. If it find a text to add a css class.

**My code looks like this :**

```
function retrieveBlicCheckedFacts(tabUrl){
    var data = {currentUrl: tabUrl};
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: API_URL_FIND,
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(respData){
            console.log(respData); //here data are printed correctly
             $("#lead, #detail").find('p').each(function() {
               for (var count = 0; count < respData.length; count++) {
                 var findCheckedFact = respData[count]["text"];
                 var str = $(this).text();
                 console.log(str);
                 if (str.indexOf(findCheckedFact) >= 0) {
                     $(this).html(
                     $(this).html().replace(findCheckedFact, "<span    class='red'> $& </span>")
          );
        }
      }
    });
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}
```

**respData is a list like this :**

```
[{"text":"test" , "type":"example" ,"_id": {"$oid": "570e686951d720724aa06fe7"}} ,{"text":"test" , "type":"example", "_id": {"$oid": "570e686951d720724aa06fe8"}} ]
```

When I debug it goes everything good, except when it comes to paragraphs, it doesn't go inside it, What can be the reason?  On manifest js I already add permissions on the selected URL that I want to make those changes. 
Please help me

Edit:
Code above is in `checker.js`.
**Here are some code from my manifest.json**, `http://*www.mydomain.rs/` is my desired domain where I want to make those changes.

```
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": [
      "js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js",
      "background.js",
      "checker.js"
    ],
    "css": ["custom-css.css"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "contextMenus",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "http://*www.mydomain.rs/"
  ],
```

**Web page code looks something like this:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="trunk">
    <div id="main">
      <div id="lead"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </div>
      <div id="detail" class="detail intext" itemprop="articleBody">
        <p> What is Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p> Why do we use it?</p>
        <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text.  </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where did you put above code? content scripts or background page? Where is `#lead`? Current web page or popup page? Provide more details please like your `manifest.json`

Comment: where is your ajax call? Did you put it in background page? If so, then it can't get the `#lead`, since background page and current web page live in different context, they will need message passing to communicate.

Comment: @HaibaraAi I edited my question, lead and detail divs are inside the page that is loaded in the browser. I also add some code from my manifest.json.

Comment: My ajax call is in an API that is connected with a database, ajax call is executed correctly cause I get all the results with it. In background page I have some other javascript function. In this API_URL_FIND I defined a variable above that gives Api route url @HaibaraAi

Comment: is your response object returning JS object or plain string, as per my experience response will return a JSON data in plain string format and you need to parse into JSON

Comment: On API response is defined like this:return Response(response=json_util.dumps(result), status=200, mimetype="application/json")

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax call is in the background page, it can't directly access the DOM of current page, because they live in different context and would need [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to communicate with each other.

Available methods would be:

1. Use [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). You could inject a content script in the current page, when ajax call is returned from background page, you could pass the returned info to content scripts, then do DOM operation in content scripts. Considering your logic, you may also want to send response from content script back to background page.
2. Use [Programming Injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi). You could wrap the DOM operation code in a script or some code blocks, then inject it from background page.

   ```
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {"code": "//Your DOM operation code here"}, function(result) {
       // Your logic to handle returned value
   });

   chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "xxx.js"}, function(result) {
       // Your logic to handle returned value
   });
   ```

   Code snippets would look like:

   ```
   function retrieveBlicCheckedFacts(tabUrl){
       var data = {currentUrl: tabUrl};
       $.support.cors = true;
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: API_URL_FIND,
           crossDomain: true,
           data: JSON.stringify(data),
           contentType: "application/json",
           success: function(respData){
               console.log(respData); //here data are printed correctly
               chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"}, function() {
                   chrome.tabs.executeScript({"code":
                       '(function(respData){'
                           +'$("#lead, #detail").find("p").each(function() {'
                               +'for (var count = 0; count < respData.length; count++) {'
                                   +'var findCheckedFact = respData[count]["text"];'
                                   +'var str = $(this).text();'
                                   +'console.log(str);'
                                   +'if (str.indexOf(findCheckedFact) >= 0) {'
                                       +'$(this).html($(this).html().replace(findCheckedFact, "<span    class=\'red\'> $& </span>"));'
                                   +'}'
                               +'}'
                           +'});'
                        +'}(' + JSON.stringify(respData) + '));'
                    });
               });
           },
           error: function(err){
               console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
           }
      });
   }
   ```

   Don't forget to add `js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js` to [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) section

   manifest.json

   ```
   "background": {
      "persistent": false,
      "scripts": [
           "js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js",
           "background.js",
           "checker.js"
      ],
      "css": ["custom-css.css"]
   },
   "permissions": [
       "notifications",
       "contextMenus",
       "storage",
       "tabs",
       "http://*www.mydomain.rs/"
    ], 
    "web_accessible_resources": ["js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"]
   ```
3. Move all this logic to content script. If you want to use this way, you may be restricted by [SOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), your content scripts would not get the right returned info if you don't enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) at your server side.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Even that I not currently sure what  I have to do,  in part 2.

Comment: @Egjupss, edited, I have not verified the code but the basic idea would be the same, you could just wrap your DOM logic then programming inject it.

Comment: I tried like that using this method it gives another arror  chrome.tabs.executeScript, also I modified manifest.json but it still isn't able to find p in divs

Comment: @Egjupss, I have debugged your code and edit the answer, please try again.

Comment: First thank you very much for your time
I'm still facing with some problems, I can't get out of this 
Now I get this error Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Failed to load file: "jquery-1.12.0.min.js". 
    at Object.$.ajax.success (chrome-extension://genm...//checker.js:52:25)
    at i (chrome-extension://genmd.../js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2:27451)
    at Object.j.fireWith [as resolveWith] (chrome-extension://genmd../js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2:28215)
I tried to fix it by adding on permsissions this:"http://*/","https://*/" and also adding tabId but nothing works

Comment: @Egjupss, did you forget to add `jquery-1.12.0.min.js` to the `web_accessible_resources` section in `manifest.json`?  Add this line `"web_accessible_resources": ["js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"]` to `manifest.json` also make sure the path is right when calling `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. I have updated the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109228/discussion-between-egjupss-and-haibara-ai).